# Can I purchase Xbox One XDK in 2022?

Tags: directx, console, xbox

My gf has an Xbox One, and I wanted to surprise her with a custom Xbox One game.

1. Are XDKs still being retailed?
2. How much do you estimate the cost?
3. How old do you have to be to purchase one?

I'd prefer not use any Homebrew, because I don't want to make her install a bunch of tools she'll never need to use again.

Comment: This looks like a question to ask a Microsoft representative, not a random collection of strangers, where even those with experience in this area might not be at liberty to discuss Microsoft developer policies on a public website like this due to NDAs and developer agreements.

Comment: Is there any direct number I can call? Because I attempted to call an Xbox representative, but the only things listed to call for were things about troubleshooting.

Comment: [There's an application form here](https://www.xbox.com/en-CA/Developers/id).

Comment: Btw, on the xbox one, you can use the community dev mode to make indie games. A full devkit will costs several thousand dollars and I believe msft restricts who they sell to

Answer (score 1):

The official "developer kits" are not for sale to anyone without an approved Publisher License Agreement or who are onboarded to the [ID@Xbox](https://www.xbox.com/en-us/Developers/id) program.

You *can*, however, make use of **Developer Mode** on a retail Xbox One or Xbox Series X|S. This allows you to write DirectX 11 or DirectX12 UWP x64 native applications using Visual Studio Community, Unity3D, or a few other engines.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-activation) and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-uwp-on-xbox-series-x-s/).